# PhoneGap + oauth.io: internal browser look-and-feel

Tags: android, cordova, oauth

I'm using oauth.io to implement authorization flow in my mobile app (Cordova, Android). It works pretty well, but there's an issue related to the style of pop-up which asks for user credentials (`OAuth.popup('provider')`).

It's beeing opened in some built-in "browser" or something and it doesn't really look good (as least on Android). It breaks all the design of my application.

So the question is: is there any way to customize the look-and-feel of this poop-up (or whatever it is)?

Comment: Yes, you can inject some parameters depending of the provider for the look of the popup. What provider do you want to use? For instance, with facebook, you have the option {authorize: {display: 'touch'}}. OAuth.popup('facebook', {authorize: { display: 'touch'}}).done(function(res) { ... });

Comment: I use Twitter and it didn't help :(